# Running out of memory on Google Colab

Tags: tensorflow, memory, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to run a demo of TF Object Detection model with Faster RCNN on Google Colab Pro GPU (RAM: 25GB, Disk: 147GB), but it fails and gives me the following error:

```
Tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:456] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 7.18GiB (rounded to 7707033600)requested by op MultiLevelMatMulCropAndResize/MultiLevelRoIAlign/AvgPool-0-TransposeNHWCToNCHW-LayoutOptimizer
If the cause is memory fragmentation maybe the environment variable 'TF_GPU_ALLOCATOR=cuda_malloc_async' will improve the situation.
```

Then it gives me these stats:

```
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1058] Sum Total of in-use chunks: 7.46GiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1060] total_region_allocated_bytes_: 15034482688 memory_limit_: 16183459840 available bytes: 1148977152 curr_region_allocation_bytes_: 8589934592
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1066] Stats: 
Limit:                     16183459840
InUse:                      8013051904
MaxInUse:                   8081602560
NumAllocs:                        6801
MaxAllocSize:               7707033600
Reserved:                            0
PeakReserved:                        0
LargestFreeBlock:                    0
```

And

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.ResourceExhaustedError:  OOM when allocating tensor with shape[2400,1024,28,28] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
     [[{{node MultiLevelMatMulCropAndResize/MultiLevelRoIAlign/AvgPool-0-TransposeNHWCToNCHW-LayoutOptimizer}}]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.
 [Op:__inference__dummy_computation_fn_32982]
```

I don't really understand why it runs out of memory allocating only 7GB on a 25GB system? How can I fix it? Here is my config file for this task:

```
# Faster R-CNN with Resnet-50 (v1)
# Trained on COCO, initialized from Imagenet classification checkpoint

# Achieves -- mAP on COCO14 minival dataset.

# This config is TPU compatible.

model {
  faster_rcnn {
    num_classes: 7
    image_resizer {
      keep_aspect_ratio_resizer {
        min_dimension: 640
        max_dimension: 640
        pad_to_max_dimension: true
      }
    }
    feature_extractor {
      type: 'faster_rcnn_resnet50_keras'
      batch_norm_trainable: true
    }
    first_stage_anchor_generator {
      grid_anchor_generator {
        scales: [0.25, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0]
        aspect_ratios: [0.5, 1.0, 2.0]
        height_stride: 16
        width_stride: 16
      }
    }
    first_stage_box_predictor_conv_hyperparams {
      op: CONV
      regularizer {
        l2_regularizer {
          weight: 0.0
        }
      }
      initializer {
        truncated_normal_initializer {
          stddev: 0.01
        }
      }
    }
    first_stage_nms_score_threshold: 0.0
    first_stage_nms_iou_threshold: 0.7
    first_stage_max_proposals: 300
    first_stage_localization_loss_weight: 2.0
    first_stage_objectness_loss_weight: 1.0
    initial_crop_size: 14
    maxpool_kernel_size: 2
    maxpool_stride: 2
    second_stage_box_predictor {
      mask_rcnn_box_predictor {
        use_dropout: false
        dropout_keep_probability: 1.0
        fc_hyperparams {
          op: FC
          regularizer {
            l2_regularizer {
              weight: 0.0
            }
          }
          initializer {
            variance_scaling_initializer {
              factor: 1.0
              uniform: true
              mode: FAN_AVG
            }
          }
        }
        share_box_across_classes: true
      }
    }
    second_stage_post_processing {
      batch_non_max_suppression {
        score_threshold: 0.0
        iou_threshold: 0.6
        max_detections_per_class: 100
        max_total_detections: 300
      }
      score_converter: SOFTMAX
    }
    second_stage_localization_loss_weight: 2.0
    second_stage_classification_loss_weight: 1.0
    use_static_shapes: true
    use_matmul_crop_and_resize: true
    clip_anchors_to_image: true
    use_static_balanced_label_sampler: true
    use_matmul_gather_in_matcher: true
  }
}

train_config: {
  batch_size: 8
  sync_replicas: true
  startup_delay_steps: 0
  replicas_to_aggregate: 8
  num_steps: 25000
  optimizer {
    momentum_optimizer: {
      learning_rate: {
        cosine_decay_learning_rate {
          learning_rate_base: .04
          total_steps: 25000
          warmup_learning_rate: .013333
          warmup_steps: 2000
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.9
    }
    use_moving_average: false
  }
  fine_tune_checkpoint_version: V2
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "faster_rcnn_resnet50_v1_640x640_coco17_tpu-8/checkpoint/ckpt-0"
  fine_tune_checkpoint_type: "detection"
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }

  max_number_of_boxes: 100
  unpad_groundtruth_tensors: false
  use_bfloat16: true  # works only on TPUs
}

train_input_reader: {
  label_map_path: "label_map.pbtxt"
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "train.record"
  }
}

eval_config: {
  metrics_set: "coco_detection_metrics"
  use_moving_averages: false
  batch_size: 1;
}

eval_input_reader: {
  label_map_path: "label_map.pbtxt"
  shuffle: false
  num_epochs: 1
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "test.record"
  }
}
```

Comment: The GPU seems to have only 16 GB of RAM, and around 8 GB is already allocated, so its not a case of allocating 7 GB of  25 GB, because some RAM is already allocated already, this is a very common misconception, allocations do not happen on a vacuum. Also, there is no code or anything here that we can suggest to change.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Thanks for the comment, I just edit to add the config file I used to train this model. This task doesn't involve codes to build the model since I only use the Object Detection API. Second, the resource allocation on my Google Colab says that I have 24GB of GPU, is there any way to make use of that 24GB then? Thank you!

Comment: Ah I just realized it's because of the images in a sample that take up a lot of memory, I changed batch-size to 2 and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into the same problem. It took me a week to figure it out. I am using colab pro+. tesla p100 GPU(16GB) was allocated to me. My image dim is (256,256,4)
and the batch size is 32. The thing is when we design a architecture we don't think about the size of params until we ran into problems like **RESOURCE EXHAUST ERROR**. Then we make some changes, trying to minimize the params. But there is also another factor that takes up the memory. That is in my case I use four separate variables to hold the tensors.

```
 block_0=layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(1,1),strides=(1, 1), activation="LeakyReLU",padding='same',name='block_5_layer_1'))(x)
 block_1=tfa.layers.SpectralNormalization(layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3,3),strides=(1,1), activation="LeakyReLU",padding='same',name='block_5_layer_2'))(x)
 block_1=tfa.layers.SpectralNormaliza``tion(layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(5,5),strides=(1, 1),padding='same',name='block_5_layer_3'))(block_1)
 # block_1=layers.BatchNormalization()(block_1)
 block_1=layers.Activation('LeakyReLU')(block_1)
 block_1=layers.Dropout(0.7)(block_1)

 block_2=tfa.layers.SpectralNormalization(layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(1,1),strides=(1, 1), activation="LeakyReLU",padding='same',name='block_5_layer_4'))(x)
 block_2=tfa.layers.SpectralNormalization(layers.Conv2D(filters=96, kernel_size=(3,3),strides=(1, 1), activation="LeakyReLU",padding='same',name='block_5_layer_5'))(block_2)
 block_2=layers.Dropout(0.7)(block_2)

 block_3=layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(3,3),strides=(1,1 ),padding='same',name='block_5_maxpool_1') (x)
 block_3=tfa.layers.SpectralNormalization(layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3,3),strides=(1, 1), activation="LeakyReLU",padding='same',name='block_5_layer_6'))(block_3)


 x = layers.concatenate(
  [block_0, block_1, block_2, block_3],
  axis=3,
  name='block_5')
```

For me **RESOURCE EXHAUST ERROR** occurred at the very first layer.
The resulted shape is (32,256,256,352) which is huge and I **suppose** those tensors are stored in the GPU itself. So this takes up lots of space and that is why TensorFlow can't allocate memory to the layers. And when I reduced its dims it worked. So I think we should also consider the shape of the variables holding the convoluted images along with the param size. Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I realized it's the problem with the images taking up too much memory in a sample size, as per https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/1817, so I went and changed my batch size to 2 and it worked